# Elasticsearch _id field is filling up field data

Tags: elasticsearch, caching

I'm seeing circuit breakers tripped messages from _nodes/stats/breaker. When I check _cat/fielddata, I see that it is mostly the _id field. Why would the field data cache fill up with the _id field?

I'm using UUIDs, so there's no point to aggregating or sorting on it.  It's possible someone is sorting on it, I'm still looking.

Is there anything else that would tend to fill the field data cache with the _id field?

Comment: How do your queries look like? What version are you on?

Comment: Version 7.17.1. There are a wide variety of queries run from different sources.  I'm still going through them. Anything other that sorting or aggregating that might load this into the cache? Thanks!